# NSUserdefault to same data from JSON

Tags: json

Good morning, I have this block of code that I am using to get exchange rates from an API JSON file. I use this function to convert a result to different currencies.  I am trying to add functionality to store the data so, when offline, it still shows a result with the last downloaded JSON file data.
I was thinking maybe use NSUserdefault? but not too sure where...
I am already using this to check if online or not.

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
// connected do something}
else{ 
// do something else }
```

Thank you for any pointer and any kind of help that could send me in the right direction.

```
func exchangeRatefunc (mycurrency: String, mapaye: Double) {

    let apiEndPoint = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"

    guard let url = NSURL(string: apiEndPoint) else {
        self.infoLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Error getting exchange rates.", comment: "")
        print("Url is not valid")
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? 0)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {

            print("No data received")
            self.infoLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("You appear to be offline!", comment: "")
            return
        }

        do {
            guard let exchangeDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("Could not convert JSON to dictionary")
                self.infoLabel.text =  NSLocalizedString("No conversion Available.", comment: "")

                return
            }

            print(exchangeDict.values)

            if let rates = exchangeDict["rates"] {
                let currencies = [mycurrency]

                for currency in currencies {
                    if let rate = rates[currency] as? Double {

                        self.exchangeRates.append("1 USD = \(rate) " + currency)

                        let myprefcurdisplay = mapaye * rate

                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                            self.myPreferedCurrencyPayLabel.updateWithText("\(myprefcurdisplay.roundTo(places: 2)) \(currency)")

                            if let date = exchangeDict["date"] as? String {
                                self.infoLabel.text = "\(currency)/USD" + NSLocalizedString(" rates updated on" + " \(date)", comment: "")
                            }
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error trying to convert JSON to dictionary")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```